# Modeling a car wheel arc: Move vertex to form an arc

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, workflow, topology, splines

I'm really noob with Blender and 3D modelling in general. I started modelling a *very* low polly car, and I wasn't careful at all about the topology, little by little I started adding some more detail to some parts, and end up trying to fix the topology also. I'm having the impression that maybe this is not so easy as to start with a good topology from the beginning.

**I'm currently trying to make the arc of the wheel resemble a semi-circle, right now is aproximated by eye.**

[image: make the selected faces describe an arc]

--

But till now I'm clueless about how to reorder those vertex **so I can make the flow of the mesh start from the arc of the wheels to the rest of the body**, this kind of flow:

[image]

Some more views of the car if needed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwPqx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIpe.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypFV2.png

Comment: it comes with practice. i sugges you to watch some tutorials first. and try modelling one part at a time rather than the whole mesh. keep the parts separated. that way it will be easier to maintain the topology and model. try to model some simple vehicles using blueprints. i can link you some tutorials if you want. Your topology is really meshy right now

Comment: I would appreciate if you could link them =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two tools that can help you achieve that.

**1) Scale to sphere (Alt + Shift + S)**

**2) LoopTools Addon to space out vertices.**

I recommend you proceed like this:

*Scale to sphere*

- Set the 3D cursor to the center of your arc. We will use it as the pivot point for scaling the vertices.
- press "." (NOT on the NumPad) to set the pivot point to the 3D cursor
- select all the vertices you want to sit on the arc.
- press Alt + Shift + S and move your mouse until the vertices align on an arc.

*Space the vertices*

- Enable the LoopTools Addon in the User Preferences
- with the vertices selected, press W and select *LoopTools* - *Space*